# Slider too large when resolution larger than 1280 x 1024

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider on my page http://aboutgreenwoodmississippi.com/ It looks fine at 1280 X 1024. However at larger resolutions, it just gets larger and larger. I am not sure how to control this. I want the slider at the top to stay just a little larger than the gallery below it.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: So set a max size

Comment: Sorry for not adding some code. This is my first post. I will be sure next time to add code to make things easier for the people that are willing to give their time to try and help. Appreciate the pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you could use images with different aspect ratio. Also as mentioned before you could set your sliders max-height to lets say 75vh or calc(100vh - 131px) - 131px is the height of your header.

Answer (score 0):

Use `max-height: (whatever the height of the container is)`
OR
Set the container's height to something like `75vh`.
OR
Set the font size to a responsive size.